# Cannot plot Quantity values with DateListPlot

Tags: plotting, bugs, time-series, units

**Bug introduced in 9.0.0 and fixed in 9.0.1**

*`Quantity` is new in 9.0.0*

---

Is there a way to use `DateListPlot` with `Quantity` values? I retrieved the following time series data from WolframAlpha:

```
gasPrices = WolframAlpha[
"us gas prices", {{"History:Price:GasPriceData", 1}, 
"TimeSeriesData"}];
```

Each data point is composed of a date and a `Quantity`:

```
{{{1993, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, Quantity[1.068, ("USDollars")/("Gallons")]},
 {{1993, 4, 19, 0, 0, 0.}, Quantity[1.079, ("USDollars")/("Gallons")]},
...
 {{2012, 12, 31, 0, 0, 0.}, Quantity[3.369, ("USDollars")/("Gallons")]} }
```

I can plot the values using `ListPlot`:

```
 ListPlot[gasPrices[[All,2]]]
```

[image]

Strangely however, `DateListPlot` produces an empty plot:

```
 DateListPlot[gasPrices]
```

[image: Empty plot from DateListPlot]

To get `DateListPlot` to produce a proper plot I have to do this instead:

```
DateListPlot[ Transpose[{gasPrices[[All, 1]], gasPrices[[All, 2, 1]]}] ]
```

[image: OK plot from DateListPlot]

Am I missing something? I would have thought that `Quantity` values could be taken directly by `DateListPlot`, as they are by `ListPlot`.

Comment: I tested your code and it seems that Units are not properly implemented in `DateListPlot`

Comment: You can also do: DateListPlot[QuantityMagnitude[gasPrices]] to remove the units.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to work in the 9.0.1 release:

```
 DateListPlot[gasPrices]
```

[image]